# Why Error on line 4: Element type "n.length" with Google Apps Script's XlmService?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, html-table

I'm trying to scrape a HTML table data, using Google Apps Script's XlmService, of which function is new to me.  But I'm getting an error, "Exception: Error on line 4: Element type "n.length" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"."  Is this due to something in this website not compatible with XlmService?  Thanks for any advice!

```
function test() {
  const url = 'https://www.tsa.gov/coronavirus/passenger-throughput';
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();
  var res1 = XmlService.parse(res);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66845645/14265469) I've managed to get some info from this site with this snippet:

```
function test() {
  const url = 'https://www.tsa.gov/coronavirus/passenger-throughput';
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();
  const res1 = Cheerio.load(res);
  Logger.log(res1('.views-field-field-2021-throughput').text());
}
```

[image]

It can be parsed about this way:

```
var dates = res1('.views-field-field-today-date').text().match(/\d+\/\d+\/\d+/g);
var col1  = res1('.views-field-field-2021-throughput').text().match(/\d+,\d+[,\d+]*/g);
var col2  = res1('.views-field-field-2020-throughput').text().match(/\d+,\d+[,\d+]*/g);
var col3  = res1('.views-field-field-2019-throughput').text().match(/\d+,\d+[,\d+]*/g);

console.log(dates[0], col1[0], col2[0], col3[0]);
console.log(dates[1], col1[1], col2[1], col3[1]);
console.log(dates[2], col1[2], col2[2], col3[2]);
```

[image]

And put the data on your sheet this way:

```
var table = dates.map((d, i) => [d, col1[i], col2[i], col3[i]]);
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1,table.length,table[0].length);
range.setValues(table);
```

**Reference:**

https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs

**Update**

Here is the updated version of the code without those clumsy RegExp:

```
function test3() {
  const url = 'https://www.tsa.gov/coronavirus/passenger-throughput';
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();
  const $ = Cheerio.load(res);
  
  var dates = $('table').find('td.views-field-field-today-date').toArray().map(x => $(x).text().trim());
  var col1 = $('table').find('td.views-field-field-2021-throughput').toArray().map(x => $(x).text());
  var col2 = $('table').find('td.views-field-field-2020-throughput').toArray().map(x => $(x).text());
  var col3 = $('table').find('td.views-field-field-2019-throughput').toArray().map(x => $(x).text());

  var table = dates.map((d, i) => [d, col1[i], col2[i], col3[i]]);
  
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1,table.length,table[0].length);
  range.setValues(table);
}
```

Comment: it's beautiful. It works perfectly.   Thank you so much for the complete codes more than what I expected!   One question!  Could you explain what [,\d+]* means in /\d+,\d+[,\d+]*/g?

Comment: `[,\d+]*` means zero or more combitations of (`,` + `one or more of digits`). It's need to match with `###,###,###` (1,234,567 for example) and `###,###` (12,345 for example). Since the columns contain figures with one and two commas. Technically it matches to figures with any number of commas between digits `#,#,#,#,#...`

Comment: Based on my new knowledge (still too scarce) of jQuery I just added the version of the code with no RegExp.

Comment: thank you again!   I ran your original and updated version for 50 iterations to check which was faster.   No meaningful difference in runtime.  However I prefer your updated version because of more understandable codes to me as a novice.