# How to pull HTML table data with Cheerio in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, html-table, cheerio

Inspired by such a convenience of Cheerio from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69335854/why-error-on-line-4-element-type-n-length-with-google-apps-scripts-xlmservic/69337145?noredirect=1#comment122572179_69337145), I'm trying to use it in the following codes.  The codes was able to pull any table data by calling class="snapshot-td2", but I'm interested in getting only those in the first table.  How can I do that?  The URL has two tables having class="snapshot-td2".  And it retrieved them in string.  How can I get them in array?  Thank you for any help!

```
function test() {
  const url = 'https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AFRM';
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();
  const page = Cheerio.load(res);

  // The next line returned the tableValue from two tables of having class="snapshot-td2".
  // What should be modified to get the tableValue only from the first table? 
  // The next line returned the tableValue in string.  What should be modified to get them in array?
  var tableValue = page('.snapshot-td2').text();
  console.log(tableValue);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in jQuery by any means so probably my solutions is quite stupid. But it works:

```
function test2() {
  const url = 'https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AFRM';
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();
  const $ = Cheerio.load(res);

  var data = $('table.snapshot-table2').find('td').toArray().map(x => $(x).text());

  var table = []
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i+=12) {
    row = [];
    for (var j=0; j<12; j++) row.push(data[i+j]);
    table.push(row);
  }

  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,table.length,table[0].length);
  range.setValues(table);
}
```

[image]

If you want an array (not a table) the `data` is the array. Every even element of which [0,2,4...] is a name, and every odd element [1,3,5...] is a value.

You can convert it into 2 columns [[name, value], [name, value]...]  pretty easy:

```
var table = [];
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i+=2) table.push(data[i], data[i+1]);
```

Or into an object {name:value, name:value, name:value...}:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i+=2) obj[data[i]] = data[i+1]);
```