# Count number occurrences of HTML code on google app script crawl using regex

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-ads-script

```
for(var x in urls){
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls[x],urlFetchOptions);
    var code = response.getContentText();
    for(var y = 0; y < messagesToCheckFor.length; y++){
      var message = messagesToCheckFor[y];
      if(code.indexOf(message) !== -1){
        bad_urls.push(urls[x]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }`
```

This code in a Google Ads script checks through all URLs for a piece of HTML, and if found, pushes that URL to an array (bad_urls). However I'd like to amend it so that it instead counts the number of occurrences of the piece of HTML and then adds each URL and the total count to an array so that I can record their values in a google sheet

I think I need something like the below to use regex to count successive matches but I'm not sure how to add the count to a variable and then push both url and count to their own array. Thanks

```
var re = /dpb-product-link svelte-1yex87k/g;
var outofStockMatch = [];
count = 0;
        while (re.exec(code)) {
          outofStockMatch = ++count;
```

Comment: And, just in case, see my answer about Cheerio, probably it makes sense to parse the html this way instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69351275/14265469

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your goal right. Probably you need something like this (to count substrings in given text):

```js
var text = 'a b c d a a e f';

function count(text, find) {
  try { return text.match(RegExp(find, 'g')).length }
  catch(e) {return 0}
}

console.log(count(text, 'a')); // output: 3
console.log(count(text, 'b')); // output: 1
console.log(count(text, 'z')); // output: 0
```

Comment: I am trying to count the number of occurrences of a piece of text within a webpage and assign the value to a variable

Comment: <code>for(var x in urls){
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls[x],urlFetchOptions);
  var code = response.getContentText();
  count = (code.match(/dpb-unavailable svelte-1yex87k/g) || []).length;
          for(var y = 0; y < messagesToCheckFor.length; y++){
            var message = messagesToCheckFor[y];
                if(code.indexOf(message) !== -1){
                    bad_urls.push(urls[x]);
                        break;
    }
    }
  }</code>

Comment: My function `count()` does exactly this: gives the number of given strings inside of given text. Try it this way: `var c = count(piece_of_text, html_code)`. `c` will be number of `piece_of_text`s inside of `html_code`

Comment: Okay but this is running in google ads scripts so count is not a function that can be used

Comment: Sorry, I think you need to make your code reproducible (executable by 'Run code snippet' button) and then I (or someone) will able to show you how it could works.