# Google apps script Xml Parse error; TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

Can anyone tell me how to fix the error in my code please, i have tried changing the value in 7 to 2, 3 and 4, all are not working.

```
function mwNetMargin(ticker) {
  var url = 'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/' + ticker + '/financials?mod=mw_quote_tab'

  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var res = html.match('<div class="cell__content"><span class="">94.68B</span></div>');

  var document = XmlService.parse(res[1]);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
    
  var trNodes = root.getChild('tbody').getChildren();
  trNodes.forEach((trNode) => {
    var tdNodes = trNode.getChildren();
    var fieldName;
    var fieldValue;
    tdNodes.forEach((tdNode, idx) => {
      if (idx % 2 === 0) {
        fieldName = tdNode.getValue().trim();
      } else {
        fieldValue = tdNode.getValue().trim();
        console.log( fieldName + " : " + fieldValue );
      }
    } );
  } );
}
```

Comment: The error suggests that `res` is `null`

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455158/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-google-apps-script

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.