# How to use REGEXEXTRACT with various possible inputs?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that has lines and lines of code. This is one example of a line where I need to use the **REGEXEXTRACT** for:

```
<tr><td class="fs-6 text-muted"><a class="link-unset" href="index.php?wid=123524&page=work-tracker&tracker=user_records&view=id">123524</a></td><td class="total-points">4</td><td><a href="index.php?page=sailor&s_id=89207">Hamyroww</a></td><td data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Who confirmed this duty?<em class='approval-notes'>Doritota, ItsMrStea1YoGirl</em>" data-bs-html="true">Sentry/SA <span class="text-muted">(0.5h)</span> <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info text-muted opacity-25 fs-6 ms-1"></i></td><td class="color-HQ">HQ</td><td>11th November 2023<span class="d-block fs-6 text-muted font-monospace"><i class="fa-solid fa-clock opacity-25"></i> 15:12:31</span></td><td data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title data-bs-html="true"><span class="text-muted bil"><i class="fa-solid fa-spinner"></i> Pending<span> </td>
```

Now the result of the REGEXEXTRACT should focus on `<em class='approval-notes'>Doritota, ItsMrStea1YoGirl</em>` **and output Doritota, ItsMrStea1YoGirl**

I tried various options in my syntax but it doesn't seem like any could work out.

**! Do note, that the 2 names can also be 1 name, and that the name can contain symbols or numbers**

What approach do you all suggest you extract every character between the ">" "<" in the above code?

Comment: Obligatory link: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) Even more so with [the flavor that Google Sheets uses](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). [Use Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19455158) to do the parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *'... What approach do you all suggest you extract every character between the ">" "<" in the above code? ...'*

Try a *match pattern*.

```
(?<=<em class='approval-notes'>).*?(?=</em>)
```

Or, a *capture pattern*.

```
<em class='approval-notes'>(.*?)</em>
```

Comment: Works alot better, but what is the class= contains " instead of a singula ' ? Gives an error.

<em class="approval-notes">(.*?)</em> for example

Comment: @TimM, a quick solution for that would be the following, _<em class=['\"]approval-notes['\"]>_.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"em.*?>(.*?)</em")
```

If you have more than one occurrence of `<em>...</em>` and you want to return them all, you could try something like this:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"em.*?>(.*?<)/em|.","$1"),"<")
```

Comment: Does unfortunately not work. See https://prnt.sc/r9u8tI427TOL for more info, but in some occassions it returns the name, other situations it returns a bit of the code but no name

Comment: what are the strings that don't return the expected result? Can you paste them here?